# Can't find laptop built-in camera

Tags: linux, drivers, arch-linux, camera

I am running arch and try to use my built-in camera. Unfortunately any program I started can't detect it. I guess the needed drivers are not installed.

I run arch linux on my computer, with the most recent updates. I checked my camera with a live usb drive of Ubuntu, and there it worked out of the box. Can I check there somehow which drivers I would need?

How can I detect it?

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0094 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b57e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And this is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

### Edit

I found a more detailed data sheet, it specified the camera with this: `CAMERA HD W/2MIC L80SR`.
Googling this didn't help me much further unfortunately.

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Comment: Yoga 510 15", but I couldn't find any specifications

Comment: You are 100% sure this device even has a built-in camera?  Because based on the information you have provided I would conclude it does not.  If it does then the device isn't compatible with Linux.

Comment: Did/does it work with another OS? Maybe it's disabled in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Can you physically see a camera on it?

Comment: The camera seems to be USB `04f2:b57e`. Anything related to that in `dmesg`?

Comment: Couldn't find any message regarding `04f2:b57e` unfortunately...

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm sure there is a camera above my screen.

Comment: Update your question and specific which OS you are using.  Just using a tag to identify the OS doesn't provide us enough information.    Identify the release date of the Arch Linux installation your using and the kernel you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound, I updated everything.